# AJAX File Check - Long delay in checking

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, load, size

I am trying to check a video is there, based on an item clicked, and then load it. If the video is larger than 10 mb this takes ages. I've currently done a work around where I check for a text file right next to it with the same name and this takes seconds to load but isn't ideal having all these text files for every video I have. I am checking if the video is there based on what is clicked and using that variable to define the video name.

Is there a way for me to check the video url without a long delay?

```
var my_video

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "./videos/" + my_video + ".txt",
    type: "HEAD",
    error: function () {
            // Don't load video
    },
    success: function () {
            // Load video
            $('.video').show().attr("src","./videos/" + my_video + ".webm");
    }
});
```

Comment: Create a serverside script that uses something like PHP's [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check if the file exists, and use your ajax to query that script instead.

Comment: I want this all to run locally, it's not web based, and I can't run a local server like Apache. Ideally I'd like to use "url: "./videos/" + my_video + ".webm",

Comment: Just create a serverside script where you pass the filename as data, and then use the serverside to check the filesystem for that file etc. Just remember to validate input properly (security and all).

Comment: I guess my question is why Ajax is taking so long and is there a way to control it to just do a parity check?

Comment: Have you looked into using the HTML5 proposed Filesystem API instead of AJAX? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: I haven't. I'll give that a read and test now. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how head calls work internally, but if it takes a lot longer for larger files, it probably gets the whole thing, and then just checkes the header on the clientside after the file is downloaded.

Comment: I don't think a clientside API will give you access to serverside files ?

Comment: I'm using --allow-file-access-from-files in the browser to run it locally offline. No risk of it being plugged into the web. If it's loading the whole thing could I partially load it somehow and still check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after much digging. I can basically load the first part of the file by using the 'headers' setting and only loading the first few bytes.

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",
        url: url,
        headers : { "Range" : 'bytes=0-16' },
        ....
```